# iterating through and moving a dynamic range of cells openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Here is what I want to accomplish:

1)insert x new columns
2)for cells( n to k) in column_i
3)move cell value x columns and y rows

here is what I have thus far:

```
#opening book 
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('testdat.xlsx')
ws=wb.active

#inserting X columns
    for i in range(5,11):
        ws.insert_cols(i)
```

attempt

```
    #iterate through cells and move them
for k in range(3,8):
 ws.move_range(C{k}:D{k}, cols=2, rows=k-1
```

which obviously doesn't work. 
I need the selection of the range to be dynamic; as in iterating

this is what I am trying to accomplish visualized

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

and so forth for all the values in that column.

Comment: What do you specifically want to do? `move_range()` accepts a `CellRange` object which means you can use it programmatically.

Comment: @CharlieClark please refer to the images which visualize what I am trying to do.

Answer (score -1):

As I said in the comments this is pretty straightforward:

```
from openpyxl.worksheet.cell_range import CellRange
cr = CellRange(min_col=2, max_col=3, min_row=3, max_row=3)
ws.move_range(cr, rows=-1, cols=2)
```

Comment: this does not answer the question. please refer to the statement "I need the selection of the range to be dynamic; as in iterating" . You have just re-written what I already have in a different format.

Comment: In that case, I do not understand what you mean. Good luck.